# python: plotting a line defining the color by a function

Tags: python, plot

I would like to draw a vector in python defining its color according to the value of a function (something like `y=f(x)`). For instance if the line has a unit length, at the beginning (`x=0`) I want to fill it with blue and at the end (`x=1`) with red, using the function to define the palette of colors.

I have tried to look at the web but without any result.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please refine the question - is it about the setting the color according to value with a specific plotting library in mind, or a general question about plotting with python

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use Python PIL for that: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm

Here is a simple example that could get you started, once you  have PIL installed:

```
import Image, ImageDraw
import math

# Create image, giving size and background color
im = Image.new("RGB", (400,400), (0, 128, 128) )

# You will do your drawing in the image through the 'draw' object
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)


def f(x):
    return math.sin(3*x)

# One loop alongside the line
for i in xrange( 400 ):
    # and another if you need a different width
    for j in xrange( 196, 204 ):

        # Calculate an x-value in the range 0-1. This is a hack
        # you might need something more general.
        x = i / 400.0


        c = f(x)

        # And calculate the colors from there
        red = int( 256*(1.0-c) ) 
        blue = 256 - red

    im.putpixel( ( i, j ), (red, 0, blue) )

im.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

Of course, I wouldn't recommend the above approach for anything requiring performance, but it might be enough for getting you out of a hurry.